# 'checkbox event' doesn't fire

Tags: events, checkbox

Ok, I've looked at a lot of examples that don't really appear different from mine. I simply want to do something (right now, just an alert), when a checkbox changes (is clicked, or whatever). My code:

```
   $(document).ready( 
      function () {
      $('input:checkbox').bind('change', function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(5);
          var skill = $("#skill" + id).val();
         alert("you processed skill number " + skill);
        })
      }) ; // end doc ready
```

One thing that MAY be different from others is that I'm dynamically creating these checkboxes with another script included like this (without the "script" tags here):

```
    <pre>src="jscript/skills_boxes.js" type="text/javascript" </pre> <br>
```

Currently that is ABOVE my 'problem' but I've had it below and my stuff still doesn't work. Is there some sort of timing issue here? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery on function.

```
 $(document).ready( 
      function () {
      $('body').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(5);
          var skill = $("#skill" + id).val();
         alert("you processed skill number " + skill);
        })
      }) ; // end doc ready
```

Comment: To explain to the OP... When you "bind" it will only bind to the events of elements currently in the DOM.  So anything added after that moment won't be included.  The `.on` function actually binds to a common parent (in this case the `body` element) and monitors for events that bubble up from child elements, regardless of when they were added.  As long as the event propagates upward through the DOM, this should catch it.  (This also presents a performance improvement since there's only one binding, as opposed to one per matched element.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I copied the "$('body').on" line into my code, but I still get no event fired when I click on these checkboxes. I'm looking at it in Firebug as well and it doesn't make it to that line **when I click**. It DOES make it there when the page loads.

Comment: Remove the guts of the change event and do an alert, maybe you are getting an error that stops it from continuing.

Comment: David, here is where it gets interesting/frustrating -- if I set a breakpoint in Firebug at that line and then let it run on thru it, the skills checkboxes never appear on the screen. If I DON'T set a breakpoint there, they DO appear. It's like they don't exist at that point. I don't know why. Thanks again for looking at it.

Comment: Ok, I removed the 'guts' and just kept the alert. No difference. But thanks.

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fXtHS/) with the basics of what you have.

Comment: I really appreciate all the suggestions on this. Since I am dynamically generating these checkboxes, it turned out that I need to do this:

Comment: <code>var catVal = '<?php echo $category;?>';
$('#category').val(catVal);</code>

Comment: Sorry. I was generating the checkboxes from MySQL via PHP, so you guys did not have enough information. However, I gleaned enough from each one of your suggestions to solve it. How should I mark this question to close it and give the proper credit? Thanks.